# SIMT warp question

Tags: gpu

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding SIMT execution on a GPU. So far I have that threads are placed in 'warps' (eg. 32 threads/warp). These threads will be of the same type and can run in parallel (but can branch & run independently).

The book I'm reading then goes on to confuse me. `'It is then up to the instruction unit to select warps that are ready to execute their next instruction, and this instruction is then issued to the active threads of the warp. Each SP core executes an instruction for four individual threads of a warp using four clocks'.`

The architecture chosen had 8 SPs, and 32 threads per warp. Therefore each SP is assigned 4 threads. Why not just assign 1 thread/SP? What does it mean by 'using four clocks?' does each instruction take 1 clock and do it does it 4 times (1 for each thread)?

Another problem I have is what if you have a warp with 32 threads each containing a conditional. What If half branch one way and half the other? From what I've read, the threads execute both outcomes? How does this work? i.e. how does it obey the program rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'using four clocks' part (in the context of the NVIDIA g80/g90/g200 family of GPUs) arises because each core is effectively a scalar ALU. It can only handle a single instruction from a single thread per clock. So to retire an instruction for a warp of 32 threads, each instruction gets executed four times over four clocks (or four times the number of clocks to execute the instruction, some take longer than a single cycle). It is a bit more complex than that because certain instruction combinations can be dual-issued, but hopefully you get the idea. On compute 2.0 Fermi parts two half-warps are dual-issued per cycle, so 32 cores retire two warps per two cycles. On compute 2.1 Fermi parts, there are 48 cores, with the same dual issue scheme, plus an additional instruction from one of active warps, if available, making the multi-processor out-of-order.

The conditional execution and branch divergence issues were covered in another question of yours, so I won't rehash it here.